# Choosing data from field

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie in terms of js, and I need to make such a calculator that does not provide data, but takes them from the field. For illustration I did this file

[jsfiddle.net/HHv3y/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/HHv3y/3/)

```
<input id="id1" type="range" min="1" step="1" max="6" value="1" onChange="sliderChange(); setValue1(this.value)" />                                                                                     
<br>
<input id="id2" type="range" min="1" max="4" value="1" step="1" onChange="sliderChange(); setValue2(this.value)" />
result: <span id="sliderStatus">12</span>
```

There are only two sliders (1 - 6 steps long) and a field for the result. In the jsFiddle is an example of a field which I would like to set.

I just need to show the value of the intersections of the two sliders, which represents an adequate entry field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple approach.

```
function sliderChange() {
    var var1 = document.getElementById('id1').value;
    var var2 = document.getElementById('id2').value;
    if (var1 == var2) {  //If both values are equal show the result
        document.getElementById('sliderStatus').innerHTML = var1;
    } else {
        alert('Not interscted');
    }
}
```

Whenever the values are equal, the resultant value will be displayed.

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P7MT2/5/)